# Must files using jsx in TypeScript have the extension tsx?

Tags: typescript, tslint

It seems as if TypeScript and tslint would not accept jsx code in a file with the extension ts. Is it mandatory in TypeScript to use the extension tsx for source files using jsx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is mandatory to put jsx in in tsx files. This is explained in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html)

> In order to use JSX you must do two things.
>
> 1. Name your files with a .tsx extension
> 2. Enable the jsx option

This was done both to mimic the extension used by `jsx` traditionally but probably more importantly because Typescript has some syntactic conflicts with jsx (for example the old type assertion operator `<type>`) so using a separate extension helps with backward compatibility.